# Postgres : ¿Cual es el Mejor utilizar vistas o setof o funcion que retorna tabla?

Tags: postgresql

Por curiosidad para ver el perfomance de la consulta, ya que dentro de la vista que es una tabla virtual se puede generar  igual que hacer una funcion  que retorna un SETOF si fuera una consulta de una tabla , si fuera de varios inner join entonces la funcion seria que retorna un table . Bueno yo los dos ultimos y no views

Answer (score 3):

En mi opinión, en el caso general, es mejor una consulta (CREATE VIEW) que una función que devuelve un SETOF. Postgresql (como la mayoría de los motores de base de datos modernos) optimiza las consultas para lograr el mejor plan de ejecución. Además se adaptan a los datos actuales de la base<sup>1</sup>.

La ventaja de la vista es que al usarla dentro de una consulta el motor de ejecución puede decidir optimizarla combinando lo que está dentro de la vista con la consulta que la usa (sin alterar los resultados, obviamente).

Cuando se usa una función la optimización es improbable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Por eso es importante ejecutar cada tanto un ANALYZE.